# Pass data from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to entities, `project` and `words` so far every time when I need to check if `project 1` had some `words`, I was passing the `project_id` to `words model`.

```
class Words
  def word_exist? project_id
    project = Project.find(project_id)
    words = project.words.exists?(self.id)
  end
end
```

Because in my controller I already set the project, do I need to do it in my model as well? Or I can pass the instance variable of the project to model.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `project` itself as parameter:

```
def word_exist?(project)
  keywords = project.keywords.exists?(id)
end
```

and in controller:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id]) # example
words = Words.new
exists = words.word_exist?(@project)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using an [`instance method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) to access the required data:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords

  def word_exist?
      self.keywords.exists?(self.id)
  end
end
```

This will be called like so:

```
@project = Project.find params[:id]
@project.word_exist?
```

Because it's an instance method on your model, you'll already have the object's data, which the instance method can then reference with `self`

---

If you wanted to find a specific word, you'll be able to use arguments on your instance method:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords

  def word_exist?(word)
      self.keywords.exists?(keyword: word)
  end
end

@project = Project.find params[:id]
@project.word_exist?("hello")
```